# aframe create complex element

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have no problem with createElement('a-whatever');

but with the situation like (from the NPM registry) :

less than sign quote a-entity arrow or less than sign quote a-entity mountain

then when I put in the correct scripts in the header of the HTML,

things work if I put in: less than sign quote a-entity arrow or 
less than sign quote a-mountain;
but i need to create many mountains/arrows/particles depending on conditions,

so using javascript createElement so far nothing works

ie. createElement('a-entity arrow');

or

createElement('entity')

then if I try less than sign quote a-eneity and try to set attributes of spe-particles or layout;  nothing gets created

Answer (score 0):

Question is not completely clear. Provide code and link to reproduce. Below syntax to create entities and set components:

```
var entityEl = document.createElement('a-entity');
entityEl.setAttribute('arrow', {attributeName: value});
```

Additional info in [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-an-entity-with-appendchild)

Comment: <a-scene>
      <a-mountain></a-mountain>
      <a-sky color="#5F818A"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>

Comment: A link with a complete example to reproduce will help. Glitch is a good option: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Edit to reword original question is better than comments.